# Security on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have been reading up on the security of MongoDB. If my web app lives on the same server as the DB, can I just set the bindIP to 127.0.0.1? I'm not sure what the best practices are, but this should only allow the actual machine to access the DB right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, if there will be local binding only local connection could be made.

This could target overall performance - but this is other topic.

***Don't forget to enable authentication - as a base security settings.***

From comments :

> When was thinking about performance then I had in mind running application server and mongo on same server.

Comment: If performance is something that is required, how much of a loss would I be facing by changing the bind ip to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @Aaron `bindIP` is unrelated to performance; this setting only determines the network interface(s) the `mongod` server is listening to.

Comment: When was thinking about performance then I had in mind running application server and mongo on same server.....

Comment: @profesor79 Thanks for clarifying: a warning on running app & database server together is sensible as both processes will both be competing for the same resources. Running all locally will save network traffic if the server is adequately provisioned or just for dev, but is likely to cause performance problems under higher load. For security best practices I would also recommend the checklist in the MongoDB manual: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/.